# Why this ERROR occurred " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.ulrs' "?

Tags: python, django

I was working with Django in urls.py I added a new path that would relate the urls.py in the app to the main urls.py. when I was about to run the server this error occurred and I don't know what is the problem
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.ulrs**'
and I am pretty sure that Django has a module name django.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ticketing/', include('Ticketing.urls')) ]
```

Comment: It's `urls`, not `ulrs`.... Looks like you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: thanks I checked and on the other file I accidently used ulrs 

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `include`, because with `include` you will read in another `urls.py`

Comment: i have another urls.py

Comment: can you please give more details on your environment? and how did you install it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you've registered your app in the 'settings.py'
And you've 'urls.py' file in the app.

Comment: I have  added the app in INSTALLED APP and also I have another urls.py for the model